# Expose Loader does not export module globally

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

We have reactjs components using some external(coffee script widgets) exported globally using `expose-loader`. It works fine on chrome, but facing issue on IE11 Globally exposed modules are not accessible. Gives below error SCRIPT5009: 'dashboard' is undefined.
exposed module as below
`require("expose-loader?widgets!../widgets");`

When we try to access `window.widgets` or `widgets` it gives undefined on IE11, but works fine on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Double-check how your script files are being inserted. I was running into a similar issue with jQuery on a webpack-powered legacy Wordpress site. I just discovered that adding `type="module"` into my script tags was breaking the `expose-loader` on IE11. As soon as I removed that attribute from my script tags, everything started firing fine again in IE11.

For example, this will break IE11:

```
<script defer src="myModule.js" type="module" crossorigin>
```

While this won't:

```
<script defer src="myModule.js" crossorigin>
```